# with-current-buffer does not move point

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Elisp this seemingly easy peace of code does not actually move the point.

```
(with-current-buffer "foo"
  (goto-char (point-max)))
```

AFAIK `with-current-buffer` should not restore the point in the target buffer.
If not, then how do I manipulate point in a buffer?

Comment: This is the code that worked - `(mapc (lambda (win)
       (unless (eq (selected-window) win)
  (with-selected-window win
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (1- line)))))
     (get-buffer-window-list emms-lyrics-buffer nil t))`

Comment: I recommend `dolist` instead of `mapc` (marginally faster, and often indents a bit better).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're confusing the buffer's point with the window's point.  If you want to move the cursor in some window showing "foo", you need to select that window while you do the `goto-char`, or else you need to use `set-window-point`.

In general a buffer has N+1 points (one is its own, and the N are for the N windows that display the buffer).

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use `switch-to-buffer` and then switch back.

Answer (score 1):

```
(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer-create "foo"))
        (goto-char (point-max))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
(set-buffer "foo")
(goto-char (point-max))
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. Btw, foo is a freshly created buffer.